# Router for specific component is not woking

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I want to route specific component in other component but when I click on the link other components are disappeared

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebar from '../componants/Sidebar'
import Navbar from '../componants/Navbar';
import Router from '../Routers/Routers'
import Answer from './Answer';
import Feed from './Feed'

const Layuot = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <Navbar />
           
           <div className="rows row">
               <div className='col-3'>
                   <Sidebar/>
               </div>
               <div className="col-9 ">
                   <div className="content">
                 
                   <Switch>
                   <Route path='/feed'><Feed/></Route>
                   <Route path = '/answer/:q_id'><Answer/></Route>
                 
                    </Switch>

                   </div>
               </div>
               </div>
           </div>
    
        </>
    )

}
export default Layuot;
```

see output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgQUT.png)
See Url
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4XPs.png)
Every component are disappeared and Feed component not ms

Comment: is there any error in the console?

Comment: No Error in console

Comment: @Dhol Keval - You need to wrap the Layout component with Router. Checkout below sandbox copy for reference https://codesandbox.io/s/old-hooks-7bnm0?file=/src/App.js